# Why does 'Date.parse' not raise an exception for an invalid date string?

Tags: ruby, date

I tried to create a method that returns a given string converted to date if the string is a valid date, else returns the string. This is the code:

```
def check_string(string)
  if date = (Date.parse(string) rescue nil)
    return date
  end
  string
end
```

When the string is:

```
"Análise de Novos Métodos Genéticos"
```

the `Date.parse` method returns a valid date:

```
#<Date: 2017-11-01 ((2458059j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

instead of raising an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) (emphasis my own):

> Parses the given representation of date and time, and creates a date object. **This method does not function as a validator.**

So if you want to validate that a given string actually is a date, you’ll have to do so through some other means (possibly [`Date.strptime`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime)). `Date.parse` seems to consider your particular input string acceptable because it contains the substring “Nov” (for November).

Answer (score 5):

Determining whether an **arbitrary string** corresponds to a valid date is extremely complicated. If possible, I would *strongly* suggest that you limit your application to only accept dates in a more restricted, well-defined format.

For example, you could use `Date.strptime` to test the string against specific format(s).

To understand what actually happened here, we can construct a *minimal* reproduction example:

```
Date.parse "Análise de Novos Métodos Genéticos"
#=> #<Date: 2017-11-01 ((2458059j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

Date.parse "Nov"
#=> #<Date: 2017-11-01 ((2458059j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

The library is interpreting this specific string to mean "1st November", because it contains `"Nov"`.